# why does this particular program print me five?

Tags: java

Please help me with this one guys! why are there arguments given to a method that is void??

```
public class C {   
    public static void main(String[] argv) {     
        int k = 1;     
        int[] x = {0, 1, 2, 3};     
        int[] y = x;     
        lurig(x, y, k);     
        System.out.println(x[0] + k + y[0]);   
    } 

    public static void lurig(int[] p, int[] q, int r) {     
        p[0] = 1;     
        q[0] = 2;     
        r = 3;   
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have a question back for you: Why can't a void method take arguments?

Comment: Java is call by value (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)  therefore `r = 3` does not modify `k`.  Also, `x` and `y` refer to the same object so `q[0] = 2;` overwrites the value written by `p[0] = 1;`.

Comment: thats the whole point!!! so why does it return 5??

Comment: @Stephen C ahh i see, but why in this case is this program giving me 5, from what?!??!!

Comment: and is anyting being return anyways since its void??

Comment: @MrMiyagi - Nothing is returned.

Comment: @MrMiyagi Your program returns 5 due to 'System.out.println(x[0] + k + y[0]);' line. This one prints to standard output.

Comment: @n1t4chi - I'm sure that is NOT what the OP is asking .....

Comment: right im asking how in the whole world can the system give me 5 when nohing is being returned from the method and k=1 whilst x and y is 0?

Comment: 2 + 1 + 2 is 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x[0]` is 0 `k` is 1 `y[0]` is 0

-> `lurig()` changes `x[0]` to 1 and `y[0]` to 2 but since y has the same reference as x it also changes `x[0]` to 2 `k` is a primitive type so it remains as 1 (completely unaffected)

-> 2 + 1 + 2 gives 5

5 is **NOT returned** it's being written out to the console. You don't have a return statement you have a `System.out` out stands for output.

Answer (score 0):

Your x and y array actually refer to the same location in memory. This means that after calling `lurig(x, y, k)` both `x[0]` and `y[0]` are 2.

If you want x and y to refer to seperate memory locations, you need to do it like this

```
int[] x = {0, 1, 2, 3};     
int[] y = new int[4];
System.arraycopy(x, 0, y, 0, x.length);
```